# Confused by the use of Parent to Child in a constructor

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, abstraction

I hope I can get some clarification regarding this issue. So a class hierarchy looks like this:
AbstractClass, ConcreteClass1 and ConcreteClass2. ConcreteClass1 extends AbstractClass and ConcreteClass2 extends ConcreteClass1:

Constructor in ConcreteClass1 looks like:

```
private final AbstractClass parent;

public ConcreteClass1( int id, AbstractClass aParent )
{
  super( id );

  parent = aParent;
}
```

I'd like to know in what case this might be useful. I don't see how ConcreteClass1 can be instantiated unless null is passed for aParent parameter. A similar constructor is used in ConcreteClass2 (i.e. it also has a parameter of type AbstractClass).

Can this ever be a justifiable design?

Comment: I don't see what's troubling you here. For example, this is exactly how SWT widget classes work.

Comment: This depends entirely on your domain. It *can* be useful to have a parent-child relation between classes, but there's no technical need for it to make inheritance work.

Comment: Looks like a tree structure to me. ConcreteClass1 objects have a reference to another AbstractClass object further up the treee.

Comment: why do you think that ConcreteClass1 can only be instantiated if the aParent parameter is null? That might help us understand your problem

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik thanks for the quick reply, I haven't used SWT widget so I'm not familiar with it, I'll check it out.

Comment: @confusopoly a tree structure was also my first hint but again I am not sure how to instantiate a first object with passing null for the AbstractClass argument. Any idea? I should mention (probably is clear!) I am new to this!! Thanks all

Comment: @TomMcIntyre sorry maybe I wasn't clear enough what I meant was using null when it first is instantiated but the following answers covered that. The top of the tree has no parent itself!

Answer (score 0):

Yes the first time you want to get an instance, you have to pass `null`, but in the subsequent times you can pass a formerly created instance.

This is pretty common and is used in many frameworks and libraries, for example Qt's `QObject` is like this and the purpose is to create a hierarchical tree of runtime instances. It's obvious that root of this tree cannot and should not have a parent.

**EDIT:** Just to give a practical example, the left tree is your class inheritance tree and the right tree is an example of runtime object tree. Note that the instance can be of any subclass of `AbstractClass`.

(CC1 means `ConcreteClass` and CC2 means `ConcreteClass2`)

```
         AbstractClass                           X (NULL)
               |                                 |
               |                                 |
        ConcreteClass1                        root:CC1
               |                             /        \
               |                            /          \
        ConcreteClass2                 ins2:CC2      ins3:CC1
                                           |          /    \
                                           |         /      \
                                       ins4:CC1   ins5:CC2  ins6:CC2
                                       ...        ...       ...
```

Comment: That's exactly what I thought but was not sure whether it's a good idea. As I also mentioned ConcreteClass2 uses a similar constructor which means potentially any object of type AbstractClass can be passed as it's parent when it's being instantiated wouldn't this cause a problem?

Comment: nope, because it doesn't mean that the tree's nodes have to be exactly **direct** instances of the top class, but just instances of any subclasses, which which makes all of them indirectly instances of the top class. In the mentioned example, each node can be instance of a different class, but all these classes inherit `QObject` and so all of the instances can be called instances of `QObject`. The purpose of the tree in this example is to have links to all created instances and release them automatically at end; some sort of garbage collection.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a practical example of the tree mentioned.

Comment: Thanks again Mousa. Note that I mentioned CC2 extends CC1 so if the constructor in CC1 takes anything of type AC, this means CC2 can be passed as CC1 parent too. So there is a potential for the wrong type to be used when different objects in the tree are being created. So why would it be desirable to create a CC1 object with CC2 as its parent?

Comment: If by "wrong type" you mean that there's some constraints in the `parent`, then you should enforce that constraint, for example by changing the parent type in CC2 ctor from AS to CC1. But speaking generally, this makes no problem. The reason for it to be desirable depends on the situation. As for Qt example, each node's lifetime is subset of parent's, meaning if parent is to be destroyed then all of its children should be too. So they don't care what type the instances are, just being instances of `QObject` suffices for them.

Answer (score 0):

It's particularly useful in any hierarchy, or inheritance type layout.

For example, say a mouse click on a GUI element.  Say your classes have a method

```
handleClick(int x, int y);
```

The first click could get handled by the bottom level component and having the parent allows the structure to pass the click to the parent.  This is similar to chaining methods/events upwards.

Alternatively, this could also be done by some outside controller that manages which elements the click method get's called on, but it might be more complicated than just using the parent model, or just less clean (though not always).

In this type of model the only time the "parent" will be null is when it's the top level element, the rest will just have the parent be one step closer to the top.